# Script won't execute location.href

Tags: javascript

Something strange is happening with my script, I have no clue why it fails.
**[edit]** I solved the problem, but still could use an answer on why this happened.

This is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type'content='text/html;charset=utf-8'>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<?php echo $err_uri;?>"/>
</noscript>
<script>

function e_fout(y,z){
    if(typeof tpag=='undefined')tpag='100';
    if(typeof y=='undefined')y='999';
    if(typeof z=='undefined')z='0';z=tpag+','+y+','+z;
      // NAME: URL 1
    var url=[window.top.location.protocol, '//',window.top.location.host, window.top.location.pathname,'error/?e='+z].join('');
    window.location.href=url;
      return false;
      }

function go_test(){
      // NAME: URL 2
    var url=[window.top.location.protocol,'//',window.top.location.host, window.top.location.pathname, 'mytest/test.php'].join('');
    alert(url);  //<== FOR TEST PURPOSE (3)
    window.location.href=url;
      return false;
    }

var gst=<?php echo ($go_test===true)?9:1;?>;
alert(gst); //<== FOR TEST PURPOSE (2)
if(gst===9){
     go_test();
     }

// *********************
alert('I'M STILL HERE...')  //<== FOR TEST PURPOSE (3)

if(glo!==9){e_fout(1,119);}

</script>
</head>
```

**The problem**:
If I run this script, it works absolutely fine in Firefox. It calls the function `go_test()`, giving the alerts **1** and **2**. Then the page is redirected to **URL 2**.

In IE, Chrome and Safari, however, it is not working. It gives me the alerts **1** and **2**, shows the correct **URL 2**, but it is not redirecting the page. It continues with alert **3** and then calls the function `e_fout()`, redirecting me to **URL 1**.

- If the line `if(glo!==9){e_fout(1,119);}` is commented out I am redirected to the correct **URL 2**
- If `//*********` is replaced with `</script><script>` it is working correct in IE and Safari, but **still not in Chrome**.

Doe anybody have an idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**
I solved the problem, but still don't know why this happened. My solution is to wrap the `if() statements` in a function, add `return false` to all the statements and call the function at the end of the `<head>` part. Now it executes as expected in all browsers.

```
var gst=<?php echo ($go_test===true)?9:1;?>;

function start(){
    if(gst===9){
        alert(gst); //<== FOR TEST PURPOSE (2)
        go_test();
        return false;
        }
    elseif(glo!==9){
        e_fout(1,119);
        return false;
        }
    alert('I'M STILL HERE...')  //<== FOR TEST PURPOSE (3)
}

start();
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: what about the development console?

Comment: it gives no errors at all.

Comment: there is probably no time between the two requests. try using setTimeout or so

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout between the different requests. There is probably not enough time to open the first page.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert('hello');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Not working, sadly. It still keeps running till the end of the script.

Comment: I solved the problem, but still don't know why it behaved the way it did. Thnx anyway for your time!